# Is it possible to not have muse over write the files when it uploads to FTP

Tags: html, hosting, livechat, muse

I'm making a Hosting company and when I finish the website, I'm going to upload a LiveChat. But in the future I will be updating the website and I don't have time to put the code inside the  everytime. So I was wondering if there's a way to keep uploading but keeping that line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you ftp directly from muse it will detect what has been changed and replace that.

But if you export html first, then do a manual upload, you can bypass your problem.